# Run methods in parallel?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

The following code is used to simulate the time-consuming works.

```
async Task DoWork(string n)
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"{n} runs {i} seconds. {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
async Task<int> F1()
{
    await DoWork("f1");
    return 1;
}
async Task<string> F2()
{
    await DoWork("f2");
    return "X";
}
```

The following code will run `F1()` and `F2()` sequentially.

```
async Task<string> Main()
{
    var f1Task = F1();
    var f2Task = F2();
    var f1 = await f1Task;
    var f2 = await f2Task;
    return $"{f1} {f2}";
}
await Main();
```

The following code can make them run in parallel. However, it looks cumbersome.

```
async Task<string> Main2()
{
    int f1 = 0;
    async Task G1() { f1 = await F1(); }
    string f2 = "";
    async Task G2() { f2 = await F2(); }

    await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => G1()), Task.Run(() => G2()));
    return $"{f1} {f2}";
}

await Main2();
```

Is there a way to do it without wrapping them in `Task.Run()`?

Comment: What is `Thread.Sleep` meant to mimic? Because that's "put the current thread to sleep until the time period is over" which is the opposite of what you'd normally want to do with async work (where `await` is "free up this thread to do other useful work until this task is finished"). The async equivalent to `Thread.Sleep` is `Task.Delay`.

Comment: It will be both io and CPU heavy. I purposely put thread sleep instead of task delay in the question.

Comment: I ask because you should have seen a compiler warning for `DoWork`. And then realised that, despite the compiler not identifying it, it's a transitive condition, and so your entire code sample runs synchronously. That's what I was struggling with because the code demonstrates no asynchronous behaviour and just runs on one thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WhenAll()` method to have your task run parallel like

```
async Task<int> Main()
{
    var f1Task = F1();
    var f2Task = F2();
    await Task.WhenAll(f1Task,f2Task);
    return await f1Task + await f2Task;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

await itself doesn't start the asynchronous operation.
Kick off DoWork with a Task like this:

```
    async Task DoWork(string n)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"{n} runs {i} seconds. {DateTime.Now}");
            }
        });
    }
```

Then you cando this:

```
   {
        var f1Task =  F1();
        var f2Task =  F2();

        return await f1Task + await f2Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it looks cumbersome. However, it can be done in a neat way. You can create a tasks array and then use *WhenAll* to wait for all of them at once.

```
var tasks = new List<Task<int>> { F1(), F2() };
var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The only condition is that all *tasks* has to return the same result type. Then result in this case is array of *int*.

I wrote a nice article about parallel processing, you can have a look at how this can be accomplished when a task is a REST call: http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/04/19/how-to-send-many-requests-in-parallel-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

> It will be both io and CPU heavy.

If you have just I/O (i.e., `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`), then you can use asynchronous concurrency:

```
var task1 = F1();
var task2 = F2();
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
int f1 = await task1;
string f2 = await task2;
```

However, since you have CPU as well (and since your method is synchronous), you'll need to push that to another thread and make it parallel.

> Is there a way to do it without wrapping them in Task.Run()?

Yes, but `Task.Run` is the simplest solution here. It can look less cumbersome than your example:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => F1());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => F2());
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
int f1 = await task1;
string f2 = await task2;
```

Technically, the `Task.WhenAll` is optional in both of these examples, but I like it since it makes the semantics more clear.